# vim remapping the hjkl

Tags: mapping, vim

I am trying to map the letter `hjkl` to `jkl` in my `.vimrc` file
so that I can have my fingers the way they always are on the keyboard, while writing in vim.

The problem is that as I map k to l, it jumps into the l to ;.
so k becomes the same as ;.
The same off course happens to all of them.

So all the keys become one because they copy through one another.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: :) never stop minimizing your finger movement!

Comment: I'm curious, so you say you're fine with using middlefinger-thirdfinger for your primary up-down movements ?

Comment: trigger finger=j,
middle finger=k,
ring finger=l,
small finger=;,

Comment: // , There's a question like this on vi.stackexchange.com, too: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3546/how-to-remap-movement-keys-to-be-used-with-the-dvorak-keyboard-layout

Comment: I find jkil to be more intuitive

Comment: In the beginning it is but once you get used to moving using only the buttons right in front of the tip of your fingers in the default position, you move about slightly faster in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was useful to adapt the move keys for an `azerty` keyboard where the default position is on jklm.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

use noremap:

```
noremap ; l
noremap l k
noremap k j
noremap j h
```

Comment: Does this also work for related bindings such as <c-w>k? Or do I have to remap all of those as well?

Comment: // , Why is it called noremap?

Comment: @37coins: `:help noremap`

Comment: The `nore` in `noremap` stands for non-recursive. It is confusing.

Answer (score 5):

Check out `:help noremap`.  This will prevent maps from recursively being mapped.

Answer (score 2):

As a follow-up to @Lie Ryan's comment, I've written [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15330610/1421642) on a similar question

Basically, you might want to consider keeping:

> **j** & **k** = **up** & **down**

since those are so primary


But then also consider:

> **l** & **;** = **left** & **right**